# How do I find a timespan from two datetime pickers?

Tags: vb.net

Here is my dilemma:
I want to find the difference in time between two timespans which are inputted by the user via two DateTimePickers.
I am having trouble reading from the dtps and then converting the inputted times into integers which i can calculate with.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated, I am sure it is quite simple, its just I have reached a complete mental blank :) 
Thanks

Comment: Yes is simple. Subtracting a date from another date gives you a Timespan. No need to write custom calculations

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting a DateTime from another DateTime gives back a TimeSpan.
And because the property Value of a DateTimePicker is a DateTime you just need something very simple like this

```
' As example, use your pickers instead
Dim t1 = New DateTimePicker()
t1.Value = DateTime.Today
Dim t2 = new DateTimePicker()
t2.Value = new DateTime(2015, 9, 30)

' Subtract the two DateTime
Dim ts = (t1.Value - t2.Value)
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalDays)
```